# Getting a Weekly info in Python with Sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, function

```
enter code here
```

i have a Table which daily Datas are stored and with this function i want to get an amount of data from ( yyyy, m, d ) until ( yyyy, m, d )

```
def weekly_cal():
    connect = sqlite3.connect('working_time_app.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT sum( fnishing - starting ) FROM working_time_app_table WHERE date between" +
                   d_u_entry and d_f_entry)
    # ( d_u_entry ) and (d_f_entry) are variables which the Dates are stored in and i got those inputs 
    # from an entry box
    sum_result = cursor.fetchall()

    show_weekly_cal_label = Label(cal_win, text=sum_result, font=("mv boli", 12), fg="white", bg="black")
    show_weekly_cal_label.grid(column=3, row=15, columnspan=5)

    connect.commit()
    connect.close()
```

the function should return the sum of Hours in the range of entered Dates the code does not show any Errors and after Running the code i do not get any Errors also . But the Label or Data will not be showed on the screen.

Comment: PS: when i use this line of code instead of the one i already have everything work perfectly .... cursor.execute("SELECT sum (fnishing - starting ) FROM working_time_app_table WHERE date between ? and ?" , (datetime.date( yyyy, m, d) , datetime.date(yyyy, m, d ))) .... but i should get the Dates from the Entry box that i have .

Comment: Change: `d_u_entry and d_f_entry` to `d_u_entry + " and " + d_f_entry`.

Comment: And add a space at the end: `WHERE date between "`

Comment: @forpas i tried your solution but it returns an Error.        File "C:\Programming\PYTHON\test projects\working time 1.3\cal_win.py", line 21, in weekly_cal
    cursor.execute("SELECT sum( fnishing - starting ) FROM working_time_app_table WHERE date between " +
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "and": syntax error

Comment: You concatenate strings, right? That `and` should be a string concatenated between the 2 dates: d_f_entry and d_u_entry.

Comment: @forpas yes i added the line u suggested just like u wrote it but still i get back an Error

Comment: Change to this: `cursor.execute("SELECT sum(fnishing - starting) FROM working_time_app_table WHERE date between '" + d_u_entry + "' and '" + d_f_entry + "'")`. Also is `fnishing` correct or should it be `finishing`?

Comment: Maybe start a bounty for this question if you dont have the anwser still.

Comment: @PythonLuaMaster i tried all those codes but still i got None as a return but now i use strptime and now i get Value format Error this is the line i wrote and causes the Error : cursor.execute("SELECT sum(fnishing - starting) FROM working_time_app_table WHERE date BETWEEN ? and ?",((datetime.strptime(d_u_entry, "%Y-%m-%d")), (datetime.strptime(d_f_entry, "%Y-%m-%d"))))